# Get highest/lowest value from many-to-many

Tags: sql

I got 3 tables, `Product(ID, Name, Price)`, `Category(ID, Name)` and `Product_Category(ProductID, CategoryID)`.

I got many to many relation between Product and Category via Product_Category. However, I want to show the lowest/highest price for each category, this is how far I got:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT MIN(Product.Price) FROM Product) AS 'Lowest price', 
(SELECT MAX(Product.Price) FROM Product) AS 'Highest price', 
Category.Name AS CategoryName

FROM Product_Category 
JOIN Product ON Product_Category.ProductID = Product.ID 
JOIN Category ON Product_Category.CategoryID = Category.ID
GROUP BY Category.Name
```

I want the price of the cheapest and the most expensive product for each category, grouped by category, like below:

```
-CategoryName   |  Lowest price  |   highest price
 Category1         50                2000
 Category2         120               300
...                ...               ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(Product.Price) AS 'Lowest price', 
    MAX(Product.Price) AS 'Highest price', 
    Category.Name AS CategoryName
FROM Product_Category 
    JOIN Product ON Product_Category.ProductID = Product.ID 
    JOIN Category ON Product_Category.CategoryID = Category.ID
GROUP BY Category.Name
```

Comment: Oh haha, that was awkward. thanks for the correction !